# FetchType.EAGER do not fetch object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My entities:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Company {

  @Id
  @Getter
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "agent_id")
  private Agent agent;

}
```

and

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Agent {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Getter
  private Long id;

  @Column(unique=true)
  @Getter
  private String name;
}
```

and problem method

```
@Transactional
public void update(Company entity) {
    Company existing = companyRepository.getOne(entity.getId());
    //System.out.println(existing.getAgent().getName());
    em.detach(existing);
    System.out.println(existing.getAgent()); // => org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
}
```

Last line causes LazyInitializationException, if I uncomment System.out.println(), everything works fine. So it looks like FetchType.LAZY. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try setting this in hibernate cfg.xml

<property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</property>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **findOne()** method  instead of **getOne()**

Method *findOne()* - internally call *entity manager.getReference(...)*.

The result of getReference() call it's returned object that is a Proxy and not the actual entity object type. So when you out of update() method you can't call proxy anymore.

I recommend you to read about [How does a JPA Proxy work and how to unproxy it with Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-does-a-jpa-proxy-work-and-how-to-unproxy-it-with-hibernate/)

The difference is that :

> `getOne()` - lazy loaded
>
> `findOne()` - is not